# Image inside of a div resizing depending on title length on Edge

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a problem with a div. It looks like this:

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="20px">
  <h1 class="mat-display-1">Welcome to $TITLE$</h1>
  <img *ngIf="logoData" [src]="logoData" class="logo" alt="logo"/>
</div>
```

Everything works ok on chrome and firefox, but on edge the image resizes depending on the length of the h1 tag. Here's the CSS:

```
.logo {
 max-width: 300px;
 max-height: 90px;
 display: block;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 margin: auto;
}
```

and the div:

```
flex-direction: column;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: flex;
```

On edge image is like:
[image]

And chrome:
[image]

Why is edge making the image bigger? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `object-fit: contain;` in **logo** class

Comment: Good to hear that! don't forget to **accept answer** if it useful.